# AngularJS ng-click function with Angular Expression parameter returning a Syntax Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am making a notes web app where I am using AngularJS framework.. I am succesfully displaying notes and I want to delete and update the notes using Unique_id .. I tried doing the ng-repeat with the notes uid in a font-awesome close icon using the a function on click

Code is below:

```
<div class="bodyContainer">
    <div class="title">
        <h3>Notes<i ng-click="updateFunc()" class="fa fa-refresh"></i></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="notesBox">
        <div class="notes" ng-repeat="Notes in txtArray | limitTo: 5">
            <remove-notes></remove-notes>
            <p class="notesTitle">{{Notes.notes_title}}</p>
            <p>{{Notes.notes_text}}</p>
        </div>
        <h3 class="emptyBox" ng-hide="txtArray.length > 0">Write Your First Note!!</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="homePaging"><a href="#notes">See more</a></div>
</div>
```

Here is the Directive Code for the `<remove-notes>` directive:

```
diary.directive('removeNotes', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<i  class="fa fa-close fa-fw" ng-click="removeNote({{Notes.notes_uid}})">',
    link: function ($scope,element,attrs) {
        element.bind('click', function () {
            element.css('color','#19B5FE');
        })
    }
}
});
```

But When I click the Icon with the click event handler it gives me a parse error:

[image: Error]

When I check the Elements panel in the console.. It renders the value of the ang expression `{{Notes.notes_uid}}`

Is there any better way to implement the delete capability.. I just want to know how to pass the `notes_uid` to my backend php code in an Async way..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are using Angular's built in directive `ng-click`, you need to remove brackets in your expression.

```
template: '<i  class="fa fa-close fa-fw" ng-click="removeNote(Notes.notes_uid)">'
```

Another sample for better understanding: `ng-value="myValue"` and `value="{{myValue}}"` are totally the same, but you should't mix them up.

### Update

It seems object Notes is not passed to the scope of directive. A possible solution is binding ng-model to directive like

```
diary.directive('removeNotes', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      note:'=ngModel'
     //bindAttr: '='
    },
    template: '<i  class="fa fa-close fa-fw" ng-click="removeNote(note.notes_uid)">',
    link: function ($scope,element,attrs) {
        element.bind('click', function () {
            element.css('color','#19B5FE');
        })
    }
}
});
```

Then in your view outside, bind models to `ng-model` like

```
<remove-notes ng-model="Notes"></remove-notes>
```

Comment: Doesn't Work.. When I check the elements panel `ng-click="removeNote(Notes.notes_uid)` remains the same `Notes.notes_uid` is not replaced with the UID .

Comment: You mean `Notes.notes_uid` hasn't been converted the UID?

Comment: It doesn't .. The Notes.notes_uid stays the same, it doesn't take the value as it should from the array which I want to send using the $http to my backend PHP code.. the element inspector shows `ng-click="removeNote(Notes.notes_uid)"` It should show something like `ng-click="removeNote(xxx)"` where `xxx` is the UID that I want to pass to the backend..

Comment: Seems Notes hasn't been passed into the scope of directive, check my update.

Comment: Still doesn't pull the Notes unique ID .. It stays the same `removeNote(note.notes_uid)`

Comment: Ah, Angular's error message is misleading, it fails to find the definition of removeNote. You'd better define it in your directive.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70449/discussion-between-chanx-and-rebornix).

Answer (score 0):

Put this in you template:

```
<remove-notes notes="Notes"></remove-notes>
```

Try this one:

```
    diary.directive('removeNotes', function () {
  return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        notes : "=notes"
      },
      controller: {
        // Define removeNote function here
      },
      template: '<i  class="fa fa-close fa-fw" ng-click="removeNote(notes.notes_uid)">',
      link: function ($scope,element,attrs) {
          element.bind('click', function () {
              $(element).css('color','#19B5FE');
          })
      }
  }
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: define removeNote function in Directive controller.

Comment: tried defining controller with removeNote function in directive but it doesnt work..